# Total aggregate over an unbounded stream in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

A number of examples show aggregation over windows of an unbounded stream, but suppose we need to get a count-per-key of the entire stream seen up to some point in time. (Think word count that emits totals for everything seen so far rather than totals for each window.)

It seems like this could be a Combine.perKey and a trigger to emit panes at some interval. In this case the window is essentially global, and we emit panes for that same window throughout the life of the job. Is this safe/reasonable, or perhaps there is another way to compute a rolling, total aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan your solution of using a global window and a periodic trigger is the recommended approach. Just make sure you use accumulation mode on the trigger and not discarding mode. The [Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/triggers) page should have more information.

Let us know if you need additional help.